# Supersymmetry transformation superstring theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers

in the study of worldsheet supersymmetry which im using Becker/Becker/Schwarz we introduce the idea of superspace by introducing a coordinate $\theta^{A}$ in addition to our $\sigma^{\alpha}=(\sigma,\tau)$. In superspace our generator $Q$ therefore takes the form $$Q_{A}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{A}}-(\rho^{\alpha}\theta)_{A}\partial_{\alpha}.$$ The infinitesimal SUSY transformation on $\theta^{A}$ can now be given as $\delta\theta^{A}=[\bar{\epsilon}Q,\theta^{A}]$. By computing this with a test function $f$, I get the following $$\delta\theta^{A}=[\bar{\epsilon}Q,\theta^{A}]f$$ which comes out to be equal $\delta\theta^{A}=\bar{\epsilon}_{B}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{B}}\theta^{A})f$. Im not sure how to simplify this to get the desired result which is $\delta\theta^{A}=\epsilon^{A}f$. Since $\theta^{A}$ forms a two component Majorana spinor am I allowed to do $$\delta\theta^{A}=\bar{\epsilon}_{B}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{B}}\theta^{A})f=(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{B}}\bar{\theta}^{A})\epsilon_{B}f=\delta^{A}_{B}\epsilon^{B}f=\epsilon^{A}f~?$$ using the property that 2D Majorana spinors satisfy $$\bar{\psi}\chi=\bar{\chi}\psi$$. I’d like to believe the previous Majorana relation is the relation that I need but if I assume that then I would get that
$$\delta\theta^{A}=\bar{\epsilon}_{B}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{B}}\theta^{A})f=(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{B}}\bar{\theta}^{A})\epsilon_{B}f=\delta^{A}_{B}\epsilon^{B}f=\epsilon^{A}f$$ and $$\delta\theta^{A}=\bar{\epsilon}_{B}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{\theta}^{B}}\theta^{A})f=0$$ which aren’t equal. Any insight would be appreciated.